# Youtube-dl doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I installed Youtube-dl and run command:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQTHVW60ov4
```

.But nothing show. youtube-dl is latest version. Thanks for help me!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the youtube-dl package in ubuntu 12.04 is outdated, the solution is to update this package adding a third party repository, in this case the webupd8 PPA.

To add it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Of course this will also update any other package the PPA contains, if you are not confortable with this manualy download and install the deb:

[https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+files/youtube-dl_2014.04.07.1-1%7Ewebupd8%7Eprecise0_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+files/youtube-dl_2014.04.07.1-1~webupd8~precise0_all.deb)

Comment: I try do what you say but it still don't work. So can you download by youtube-dl ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It worked fine to me.

Comment: Here is photo: https://flic.kr/p/n5Xzjt
It don't show anything.

Comment: I mean what part of the instructions I gave you did not work? Did you try to use youtube-dl after updating it?

Comment: Both updating and installing by .deb file. I try reinstall, upgrade,... but same result. 
Haizz. Thank you for help me, I think I will ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

the uploader has not provided the priviledge of downloading the content thats why youtube-dl is finding it unable to download. So enjoy watching it online. there is no problem with youtube-dl.

Comment: Thank for help.I used to it on Jan, 2014 but it not work now. Why can everyone use it and don't I ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following *single* command:

```
youtube-dl --version && \
sudo youtube-dl --update && \
youtube-dl --version && \
youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQTHVW60ov4'
```

This should hopefully get you up and running. If you have trouble perhaps post the terminal output from these commands, there might be some clues there...